# IF function returning "value_if_false" as a blank string instead of a blank number

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B17),ISNUMBER(H10)),B17-H10, "")
```

My issue is that value_if_false is converting cells to strings and I'm looking for a way to return a blank number cell instead of a blank string cell.

All of the options I have tried will return "0", which is still a value, and is messing up my graphs, or polluting the data with non-numbers so it is not graphable.

I have tried Format>Number>Number, but it is not changing the cell type.

Comment: Have you tried =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B17),ISNUMBER(H10)),B17-H10, 0)? When I check both TRUE and FALSE outcomes, =ISNUMBER pointed at the cell with your code still gives me TRUE.

Comment: @badermart That does return a number, but it returns "0", which is my problem. I do not want the graph to plot the zero value. I need to output a number cell but not a number value, if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried: =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B17),ISNUMBER(H10)),B17-H10, )  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this like:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B17), ISNUMBER(H10)), TEXT(B17-H10, "0"), )
```

or like:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B17), ISNUMBER(H10)), TEXT(B17-H10, "#"), )
```

Comment: @AvaLynn TEXT() formula is able to convert content of the cell into text format and 0 or # tells that you want to show that content as it would be actual number. in other words: if you put 2+2 in calculator it will give you 4 byt imagine calculator where you can type latters instead of numbers and you type in two+two... calculator does not know how to sum it nor what is "two"